# Symfony2 - Viewing uploaded files in development environment?

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I'm currently writing an entity class for an image to go in gallery and am having some trouble getting the path of the image in the development environment. The image is there, the entity finds it fine, it's all in the right place and in the production environment it'd work just fine, the problem is easy to see when I show you the URL for both production and dev environments:

Dev (doesn't work):

```
http://misa/dwright/app_dev.php/bundles/dwiportfolio/albums/1/1.jpg
```

Prod (works):

```
http://misa/dwright/bundles/dwiportfolio/albums/1/1.jpg
```

What do I have to do to make the entity aware that it has to look up another level to get the right directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually an issue in the template that Symfony and Twig solve.

In the template I had:

```
<img src="{{ gallery.coverImagePath }}" alt="" />
```

When it needed to be:

```
<img src="{{ asset(gallery.coverImagePath) }}" alt="" />
```